# Как удалить пустой массив из многомерного?

Tags: javascript

Есть многомерный массив:

```
let arr = [ 
    ['bmw', 1, 0, 3, 4], 
    ['audi', 2, 3, 4, 0], 
    ['', '', '',], 
    ['tatra', 32, 0, 74, 5], 
    ['', '', '',], 
];
```

Как удалить пустые массивы из многомерного?

Comment: А где тут пустые массивы? Ни одного не вижу.

Comment: Пустой - это заполненый только пустыми строчками? Или там может быть и набор `null` и/или `undefined` или вообще не иметь элементов?

Comment: Пустой, в смысле, с пустыми строчками

Comment: все элементы должны быть пустыми строками? или достаточно чтобы первый элемент был пустой сторокой?

Comment: В моем случаи, все элементы массива должны быть пустыми строками.

Comment: Вы должны принять ответ @PavelNazarian, а не мой :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
const arrays = [ 
    ['bmw', 1, 0, 3, 4], 
    ['audi', 2, 3, 4, 0], 
    ['', '', '',], 
    ['tatra', 32, 0, 74, 5], 
    ['', '', '',], 
];

for (let i = arrays.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {  
  if (arrays[i].every(item => item === '')) arrays.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(arrays);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Подходит!

Comment: @Cobra777 Обращайтесь! Упростил алгоритм, проверяйте!

Comment: EzioMercer -  супер!! Спасибо, точно что нужно!!!

Answer (score 4):

На всякий случай еще вариант - через `filter`

```js
let arr = [ 
    ['bmw', 1, 0, 3, 4], 
    ['audi', 2, 3, 4, 0], 
    ['', '', '',], 
    ['tatra', 32, 0, 74, 5], 
    ['', '', '',], 
];

let new_arr = arr.filter(e => !e.every(el => el === ''));

console.log(new_arr);
```

Comment: Смотря на ваш ответ, хочется удалить свой ответ... Боже, как же мне фильтр в голову сразу не пришёл....

Comment: @EzioMercer Зато у вас используется мутирующий метод splice.  Может человеку так удобнее будет. Чем больше ответов, тем лучше )

Comment: Не оправдывайте меня!)) Можно просто написать `arr = arr.filter` и будет вам мутация))

Comment: Единственное у вас поменять бы сравнение на строгое сравнение, вообще цены не будет вашему решению))